# 'MySQL server has gone away' and access denied when trying to change 'wait_timeout'

Tags: mysql, flask, hosting, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a website using Flask (Python) and I have all the application files on my computer but I use an external host (InMotionHosting) for the MySQL database that probably has settings that I can't change.

The problem is that I very often get the error code:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006,'MySQL server has gone away')
```

I think this is due to the short "wait_timeout" or/and the "connect_timeout" variables that I can't change.

**GLOBAL VARIABLES:**

wait_timeout=30

connect_timeout=10

max_allowed_packet=5242880

**SESSION VARIABLES:**

wait_timeout=610

max_allowed_packet=5242880

```
set global wait_timeout=600;

Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Is there something I can do by myself or is this something I need to ask the host about? (I am a completely self thought newbie so would appreciate as educational answers as possible besides plain instructions if there is something I can do by myself. Thanks a lot!)

**EDIT:**
As this is a shared hosting I can't change the MySQL settings and I need to find a way to solve the problem by changing my Flask app code.